# Vagrant error on creating disk Hyperv Windows 10

Tags: vagrant, hyper-v, disk, oncreate

I retrive that error when i try create disk sized.

```
Script: resize_disk_drive.ps1
Error:

Failed to resize disk E:\vagrant\rancher\.vagrant\machines\ubuntu\hyperv\Virtual Hard Disks\generic-ubuntu1804-hyperv.vhdx for VM VirtualMachine (Name = 'ubuntu-teste') [Id = 'a450e7ab-a67e-4c2b-942a-cbca16be5640']: Falha ao redimensionar o disco virtual.

O sistema não pôde redimensionar 'E:\vagrant\rancher\.vagrant\machines\ubuntu\hyperv\Virtual Hard Disks\generic-ubuntu1804-hyperv.vhdx'.

Falha ao redimensionar o disco virtual.

O sistema não pôde redimensionar 'E:\vagrant\rancher\.vagrant\machines\ubuntu\hyperv\Virtual Hard Disks\generic-ubuntu1804-hyperv.vhdx': Não foi possível concluir a operação de redimensionamento solicitada porque ela pode truncar dados do usuário residentes no disco virtual. (0xC03A0025).
```

My manifest:

`config.vm.disk :disk, size: "50GB", primary: true`